# Jenkins Change the Directory and install the Software

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins pipeline script stage to connect the SSH remote machine, second stages is i have folder name called software like /home/software inside this folder i have JDK RPM package.

When my jenkins job will run it will not listing the RPM file which ever i having inside the  /home/software folder. Below the code.

```
node {
  def remote = [:]
  remote.name = 'domain'
  remote.host = 'domain-poc.com'
  remote.user = '*****'
  remote.password = '******'
  remote.allowAnyHosts = true
  stage('Remote SSH') {
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -lrt"
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done"
  }

  stage('JDK INS') {
      dir('sudo /home/software') {
      sh 'ls -lrt'
}  
      input 'JDK Installtion'
}

}
```